# Apply CSS to all but last element?

Tags: html, css

I've got the following html:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a>list item 1</a></li>
  <li><a>list item 2</a></li>
  ...
  <li><a>list item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to apply a border to all the `<a>` elements except the last one.

I've been trying this:

```
.menu a {   
  border-right: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.menu a:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
```

but I end up with a border on none of the elements, I guess because the `<a>` in each case is the last of type.

How can I do this? I'd prefer to use only CSS if possible, and I'd like IE9 compatibility if possible.

Comment: Change your selector to `.menu li:last-of-type a` **Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/ybou5hhx/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change:

```
.menu a:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
```

to:

```
.menu li:last-of-type a {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```css
.menu a {   
  border-right: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.menu li:last-of-type a {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a>list item 1</a></li>
  <li><a>list item 2</a></li>
  <li><a>list item 3</a></li>
  <li><a>list item 4</a></li>
  <li><a>list item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you surmised, the rule you were using was targeting every `a` because it was the last child within each `li`. Just move the `:last-of-type` to the `li` instead.

Comment: I believe OP wants to select all `li` **but** the last one. This will select the last `li`.

Comment: @choz "I want to apply a border to all the <a> elements except the last one." That's what this does

Comment: I just dont agree with more implementations to remove the border on the last li..  yes indeed, this does the job but I think its better to just apply the borders to all but the last one..

Answer (score 22):

You can combine your two CSS properties by using `.menu li:not(:last-child) a` for the elements you want to have a border. As choz points out in the comment below, it's crucial to have the `li` after `menu` because every `a` in the `li` is the last child in its current context. Thus, the pseudoclasses should apply to the `li`.

```
 .menu li:not(:last-child) a {   
  border-right: 1px dotted #ccc;
  }
```

Comment: This will not work since every `li` only has 1 anchor child. This will select none because every `<a>` is considered the last child.

Comment: the :last-child here is not applied on <a> but on <li>. It reads as "every <a> that is under a <li> which is under a .menu where the <li> is not the last <li>"

Answer (score 2):

To select all `li`s but **not** the last one, you can use this.

```
.menu li:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

To apply to **not** the last `a` element, you can do this.

```
.menu li:not(:last-child) a {
    border-right: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting a default rule for all elements and then undoing it for the last one, you can just set the rule for all elements except the last one by using `:not()`:

```css
li:not(:last-of-type) a {
  border-right: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will do that like this

```
  .menu a {   
      border-right: 3px solid red;
  }
  .menu li:last-child a {
      border-right: none;
  }
```